# How to create a repeating loop in python with sympy, without changing one variable in the loop

Tags: python, sympy, spyder

so basically I have encountered a problem where I have made my loop, but since one of the variables is defined before the actual assignment, the code stops working. [the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTHsZ.png).
Another thing is that I'm working in Spyder, and I don't know why, but if I try to code so that the program collect variables initially (which is essential for this purpose), the program encounters an internal issue. Any ideas on how to ask for user input in Spyder?
Thanks to everyone in advance

Basically, what I want this to do is to differentiate functions, and the with these derivatives create a maclaurin series. When the actual error ((r-j)/r) is smaller than the stopping variable s, I want the program to stop and display the result, but I don't know what is wrong.
The second thing I want to achieve is to get to know how to gain input from the user in the program.

Comment: Please, copy the code into the question so that we can easily help you.

Comment: Hi, sadly I can't. This is an assignment for school, and I'm afraid that the algorithm will catch it and count as plagarism, which would have very tough consequences for me. That's why I chose to post a picture of it instead

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is, in text form, your code (sorry, plagiarism argument is not valid around here)

```py
q = sympy.Function('q')
q = sympy.diff(f)

def main():
    a = sympy.Function('a')
    a = sympy.diff(q)
    j = sympy.function
    j = 1+(1/sympy.factorial(count))*q
    r = sympy.Function('r')
    r = j+(1/sympy.factorial(count+1))*a
    if ((r-j)/r)>s:
        count = count + 1
        q = sympy.diff(a)
        j = r+(1/sympy.factorial(count))*q
        r = j+(1/sympy.factorial(count+1))*a
        main()
    else:
        print(f"Answer{r}")
```

In the middle of an obviously very confused code, and even more confused situation with that "plagiarism" stuff (don't worry, if you have a working code at the end of your effort, there is no way it will look similar enough to your original to be detected as plagiarism because I've posted it here:D) there is actually a good question, and I remember that I while ago I had to scratch my head to understand what was happening in a similar situation.

The problem you have here, is that you can't compute `sympy.diff(q)` in `main` function, before assigning something to `q` in that same function later.
Because of the line `q = sympy.diff(a)` that you have later, `q` has to be a local variable (unless you say otherwise, see later). That's default behavior in python: a variable that you assign in a function is a local variable.

But because you are reading this variable before, in the previous line (the one that triggers the error) `a = sympy.diff(q)`, then python has a problem: the local variable `a` doesn't exist yet.

Without the future `q = sympy.diff(a)`, `q` would have been "read-only" inside `main`, and python would have done what you probably expect: read the global variable `q`.

So, your real problem is not really that line. Your real problem is the line `q = sympy.diff(a)`.

Because even without the current error, that line would not do what you expect it to do. You probably expect it to alter `q` so that in the subsequent recursive call of `main`, `q` has this new value for now on. Not to create a local value `q`, and have the next call of `main` start over with the global value of `q`.

You have several options here.
One would be to declare `q` has global. Just add line `global q` at the beginning of your `main`, and `q` is now the global variable.

A cleaner way would be to pass q as an argument to main.

Note that you'll have probably the same problem with `count`. You should also either declare it as global, or, neater way, pass it to main.

Note also that this would solve only syntax errors (well, not even all. `j=sympy.function` is meaningless for example). But there are many other errors here. The least serious being your strange habit to create a `Function` and immediately delete it by overwriting it by another function or expression.